# In my android app Font Acme shows perfectly in xml but not working when i run the application

Tags: android, fonts

I am trying to use font-family acme in android. Though it looks ok in my XML preview but when I run the application it doesn't work in my app.

When I am using cursive font it's working fine. I haven't added any font programmatically in my java file.

Is there any point I am missing while implementing it?

My XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:background="@drawable/login_gradient"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appname"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/acme"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/company"
        android:textColor="@color/lightgray"
        
        
        android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/company"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appname"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appname"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dp"

        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="30dp">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/userrole"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                android:ems="8"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
                android:spinnerMode="dialog"
                android:visibility="gone"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"

                />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/username"

                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableStart="@android:drawable/sym_action_email"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/sym_action_email"
                android:focusable="true"

                android:fontFamily="@font/acme"
                android:hint="@string/user_id"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/custom_edit_text_cursor"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"

                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:drawableStart="@android:drawable/ic_lock_idle_lock"
                android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_lock_idle_lock"
                android:fontFamily="@font/acme"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"

                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/custom_edit_text_cursor" />


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/default_button"
                android:fontFamily="@font/acme"
                android:text="@string/sign_in"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/changepassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/default_button"
                android:fontFamily="@font/acme"
                android:text="@string/change_password"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/darkblue"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/exit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/default_button"
                android:fontFamily="cursive"
                android:text="@string/exit_app"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/exit2"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
                android:background="@drawable/cross"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_marginLeft="23dp" />





        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/user_profile_photo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appname"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/vector"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="90"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/settings"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/share"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/add_button_selector"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,UnusedAttribute" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/versionname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/acme"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
            android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
            android:text="Version 12.0.3"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText,UnusedAttribute" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sim"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/simtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:text="@string/currently_you_are_using"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
            android:visibility="gone" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you write java / kotlin code to set font ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Follow Steps given below**

1)First download the .ttf file of the font you need (sans.ttf). //use your font

2)Place it in the assets folder. (Inside assets folder create new folder named fonts and place it inside it.

3) Use the following code to apply the font to your TextView/EditText:

**In Coding**

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/sans.ttf"); 
textView.setTypeface(font);
```

You can create method of it and use to multiple textview or edit text

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have `font` folder under `res` folder and it contains the fonts you are using.
2. Change the line

`android:fontFamily="cursive"`
to
`android:fontFamily="@font/cursive"`

3. Check if you have the bold version of font `acme` font as you are calling
   `android:textStyle="bold"` on every `textView`

and if you don't have bold version then remove `android:textStyle="bold"` and try running application

Comment: Thanks.The font was Regular so that was the problem i guess. Though i used asset folder later but your solution worked too. Thanks again.

Comment: If this answer helped you then you can accept and upvote it. It will let others know you have found the solution.